# problem with login node on maas via ssh

Tags: ssh, maas

I've a problem with the login on nodes via ssh. 
After I've installed MaaS, added the ssh key on MaaS,added 2 nodes, made them in ready and then in allocated status, activated the power on using virsh, run the ubuntu's installer on 2 nodes, re-boot the VMs using their HD....

when I try to connect them via ssh from MaaS svr they want the password. 
the prompt of node is

Ubuntu14 login:

why? I've lost some steps?

Comment: I've resolved it, how can I close it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my fail in configuration steps of MaaS. I've resolved that.